# Why does the eigenvalues of an angular frequency matrix are the natural frequency? (INTUITION)

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, differential-equations, eigenvalue, matrix-model

lest say we have a system of differential equations of some coupled oscillator such that:
$$\overrightarrow a = [w^2]\overrightarrow x$$

if we find the eigenvalues of $[w^2] = \lambda$ why those eigenvalues are the natural frequency of the system?

I see the matrix of angular frequency as a linear transformation  and the eigenvalues as the factors by which the eigenvectors stretch such that eigenvectors remain in the same line after the transformation

if the eigenvalues are the natural frequency what are the eigenvectors?

Answer (score 0):

The acceleration is the second derivative of the position i.e. $a \equiv \ddot{x}$.

This means that the you have managed to decompose the couple system of oscillators into independent modes (to state it a different way, you have found the transformation that diagonalizes the matrix). We call these eigenvectors the "natural"/["normal" modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mode) and (the square root of) their eigenvalues "natural frequencies" -- because these reorganized degrees of freedom now behave effectively like decoupled oscillators oscillating with the natural frequency (since we can interpret the equation for each eigenmode in analogy with a harmonic oscillator).

Comment: let's say we have 2 solutions for $\lambda$ you say that each solution is a decoupled oscillator?

Comment: Exactly. You might find interesting visualizations of normal modes.